# VisualStudio2017のDjangoプロジェクト内でのjavascriptのデバッグ実行方法

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, django

VisualStudio2017を用いてDjangoプロジェクトを開発しています。
その中で使用している、javascriptのデバッグ実行が出来ません。
javascriptのデバッグを有効にする方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。

javascriptのコードにブレークポイントを指定して、デバッグ実行しましたが、
そこで止まらずにスルーされます。

開発を進めるにあたって、ステップ実行できるかどうかで、
かかる時間が大きく変わる為、なんとかしてやり方を見つけたく。。。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

DjangoはWebサーバー上で動作しますがJavaScriptはWebブラウザー上で動作するためデバッグ方法が全く異なります。
Visual StudioもASP.NETであればWebサーバーと協調することでWebサーバーのコードと共にJavaScriptのデバッグも可能ですが、質問のDjangoに関してはWebサーバーはPython自身がホストしてしまっているためこの機能は使えません。

なお、各WebブラウザーはWebサーバーに依存しないJavaScriptデバッガーを持っているためVisual Studio上ではなく各Webブラウザー上のデバッガーを使用されてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど。。。VSでは出来ないのですね。
ブラウザの方で試してみます。
ありがとうございました。